# What is the relationship between the React rendering cycle and the React component lifecycle?

Tags: reactjs

By "React rendering cycle" I mean the process of rendering, reconciliation and committing that's referenced in [these](https://dev.to/thee_divide/reconciliation-react-rendering-phases-56g2) [blogs](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-slow-render-before-you-fix-the-re-render).

And by "React component lifecycle" I mean the lifecycle stages of mounting, updating and unmounting that can be observed by developers directly in their components using componentDidMount(), componentWillUnmount(), etc.

Is there any relationship between the two or are these completely different concepts? I've seen a lot more info about the latter rather than the former so is the former something we shouldn't worry about at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my knowledge `render` is itself a function, that React is offering us, to show our JSX HTML code on the UI screen, thats only method we must define in our class `React.Component` thats subclass is render, remains methods are optional not mandatory like render, when we talk about lifecycle it includes everything all methods of the component,

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
  }
}
```

this example show us, `Hello World` html code will be taken by React and will get rendered on screen,
so `render` gets called in react component lifecycle always,
the `Mounting` phase is like this `constructor()`--> `getDerivedStateFromProps()` --> `render()` --> `componentDidMount()`

the `Updating` phase --> `getDerivedStateFromProps()` --> `shouldComponentUpdate()` --> `render()` --> `componentDidUpdate()`

when you want to write the logic seek for other optional methods, check what you want to do at what time of interval, then use that function,
for example, `componnetdidmount` will be used to make `rest apis` call, as render is already completed its execution and rest apis http communication takes some time, so ui screen wont get blocked,
when you want to send html jsx code to react use render